# Pyspark: efficient way of counting distinct "On" signals from high fixed-frequency data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Pyspark to create data pipelines from a high fixed-frequency data source. That is, the signals report their states at a set frequency instead of when they change states. I know how to do what I need to do but I feel like there is a more efficient way to do it. I'm currently working on a workflow in which I need to determine the number of distinct "On" values from the source. The data is in the following structure:

```
Signal_Value   Timestamp
    Off            1
    Off            2
    On             3
    On             4
    On             5
    Off            6
    Off            7
    On             8
    On             9
    Off            10
```

So in this case, the number of distinct "On" signals is 2 even though there are 5 total values of "On" (I'm defining distinct signals here as groups of On's). Right now my process is to select the data, order it by timestamp, and then iterate through the entire list of signals and add 1 to a counting variable each time the loop encounters a situation where the current signal is "On" and the previous signal is "Off". It seems inefficient to loop through the entire list. Is there a better way of doing this?

For more detail, my code looks something like this:

```
df = spark.sql("select id, signal_value, timestamp from database.table")

# Following functions used at the bottom for map() & reduceByKey() functions

def key_value_map(x):
     key = x[0]
     value = [tuple((x[1],x[2]))]
     return (key,value)

def reduce(x):
     return x+y # combining tuple-lists

def time_order(x):
     id = x[0]
     signal_list = x[1] # has structure: (signal_value, timestamp)
     sorted_signal_list = sorted(signal_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
     return (id, sorted_signal_list)

def metrics_map(x):
     id = x[0]
     signal_list = x[1] # has structure: (signal_value, timestamp)
     count = 0
     for i in range(1, len(signal_list)):
          value = signal_list[i][0] # 0th element is signal_value
          previous_value = signal_list[i-1][0]
          if value == "On" and previous_value  == "Off":
               count += 1
     return (id, count)

mapped = df.rdd.map(key_value_map)
reduced = mapped.reduceByKey(reduce)
mapped2 = reduced.map(time_order)
mapped3 = mapped2.map(metrics_map)
result = mapped3.collect()
```

Comment: Any reason for not using DataFrame API instead of RDD? Can you add the expected  output?

Comment: I've just found it to be easier to work in RDD's for this type of data; it gives me more fine-grained control and has seemed to be a lot simpler for the type of work I've been doing with this data source. Although it may be that this specific problem might work better using the DataFrame API. The output will just be the ID and the count of distinct occurrences of the "on" signal (see above for definition of "distinct occurrences").

Comment: I see a lot of for loops. Dataframes can be sorted by column on their own, and is more performant on large datasets. Otherwise, use the database to sort things

Comment: You can use Spark sql lag function in a dataframe to get previous rows

Comment: Ah okay. So I could do a lag and count every occurrence of an "On"-"Off" pair? Yeah, if I'm thinking about this correctly, this might be better.